# CSS conditions factorization

Tags: css

I know the basics of CSS but haven't found an answer to this.

Previously, I had :

```
li[data-sizex="1"] .widget.widget-jenkins-view-build-status
```

to apply a certain style to all the widgets of this kind under li tags with sizex set to 1.

But now I want to apply it to those with sizey set to 1 too, so I wrote :

```
li[data-sizex="1"] .widget.widget-jenkins-view-build-status, li[data-sizey="1"] .widget.widget-jenkins-view-build-status
```

It works, but here's my question : is there a way to regroup/shorten/factorize this, to avoid repetition of the widget, without adding new elements such as classes ? A pure factorization like in math : A with C or B with C <==> (A or B) with C .

Thank you.

Comment: You might want to consider Sass, Less or somthing a like, in which you can define a set of rules and extend it or just include it in other classes. https://sass-lang.com/guide#topic-6

Comment: In a pre-processing format during development, yes (see Sass, et al). In the pure CSS that ends up in the UA, I think the simple answer is no.

Comment: Itay Gal, I use Less for another project and I like it a lot, but this was only a one-time issue, and I asked most of all out of curiosity. I stuck with the repeating solution, for the moment it's not a big deal.
Thanks a lot to you two for answering though :)